# getting Error when i ran ng serve after ng build

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, npm-install

I am working on my first Angular app, I'm setting up an existing angular app on my local machine.
I got the following error when I ran `ng serve`

> ERROR in
>   src/app/common-componets/directives/dropFile/drop-file.directive.ts(47,21):
>   error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | ArrayBuffer' is not
>   assignable to a parameter of type 'string'.   Type 'ArrayBuffer' is
>   not assignable to type 'string'.
>   src/app/common-componets/input-image/input-image.component.ts(58,13):
>   error TS2322: Type 'string | ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type
>   'string'.   Type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'string'.
>   src/app/dashboard/dashboard/components/new-community/new-community.component.ts(248,15):
>   error TS2322: Type '{ area: string; carrera: string; name: any;
>   publicado: boolean; resume: string; urlPhoto: any; filtros: null;
>   urlVideo: any; key: string; uid: string; activeCommunity: false;
>   positionCommunity: false; ... 9 more ...; position: number; }' is not
>   assignable to type 'IComunidad'.   Property 'briefingTags' is missing
>   in type '{ area: string; carrera: string; name: any; publicado:
>   boolean; resume: string; urlPhoto: any; filtros: null; urlVideo: any;
>   key: string; uid: string; activeCommunity: false; positionCommunity:
>   false; ... 9 more ...; position: number; }'.
>   src/app/modals/upload-users-csv/upload-users-csv.component.ts(34,11):
>   error TS2322: Type 'string | ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type
>   'string'.   Type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'string'.

```
npm v 6.4.1 
Angular CLI: 7.3.5  
Node: 10.15.3  
OS: linux x64  
Angular: 6.1.10  
... animations, common, compiler, core, forms, http
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router    

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect          0.8.4
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.13.4
@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr   0.8.4
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer    0.13.4
@angular-devkit/build-webpack      0.13.4
@angular-devkit/core               0.8.4
@angular-devkit/schematics         7.3.5
@angular/cdk                       6.4.7
@angular/cli                       7.3.5
@angular/compiler-cli              7.2.12
@angular/fire                      5.1.0
@angular/flex-layout               7.0.0-beta.24
@angular/material                  6.4.7
@ngtools/json-schema               1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack                   7.3.4
@schematics/angular                7.3.5
@schematics/update                 0.13.5
ng-packagr                         4.7.1
rxjs                               6.2.1
typescript                         3.1.6
webpack                            4.29.0
```

Does anybody know, how to solve it ?

Comment: The error clearly states type incompatibility with the exact component name and line number. `image.component.ts(58,13): error TS2322: Type 'string | ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to type 'string'. `

Answer (score 0):

Argument of type 'string | ArrayBuffer' is not assignable to a parameter of type 'string'

Means you need an if around your assignment

```
if (typeof val === 'string') {
  otherVal = val;
}
```

That way the compiler knows that you have a string and not an ArrayBuffer

Comment: Thank you for replying Adrian Brand.  


If my code is this
`convertImage(file: File) {
                const reader = new FileReader()
                reader.readAsDataURL(file)
                reader.onload = () => {
                        this.base64.emit(reader.result)  <===== ERROR LINE
                }
        }`
How to solve this?